# How can my Chrome extension to trigger a function when pressing enter on input?

Tags: javascript, html, events, google-chrome-extension, event-handling

I've made a simple currency converter Chrome extension, and I'm trying to get it to trigger my `convert` function when hitting enter on my number input with the id of `amount`.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>convertFrom Currency Converter</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <div class="convertFrom">
      <select id="convertFrom">
        <option value="ETH">ETH</option>
        <option value="BTC">BTC</option>
        <option value="SOL">SOL</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="convertTo">
      →
      <select id="convertTo">
        <option value="BTC">BTC</option>
        <option value="ETH">ETH</option>
        <option value="SOL">SOL</option>
        <option value="USD">USD</option>
      </select>
    </div>
        <div class="amountToConvert">
      <input type="number" placeholder="0.05" id="amount" autofocus required>
    </div>
    <div class="convertButton">
      <button type="button" id="convertButton" name="convertButton">Convert</button>
      <script src="popup2.js"></script>
    </div>
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
  <script src="popup2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("convertButton").addEventListener("click", convert);

document.getElementById("amount").addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    convert();
  }
});

function convert() {
  let convertFrom = document.getElementById("convertFrom").value;
  let convertTo = document.getElementById("convertTo").value;
  let amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;

  let url = `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=${convertFrom}&tsyms=${convertTo}`;

  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      let rate = data[convertTo];
      let result = amount * rate;
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = `${amount} ${convertFrom} = ${result.toFixed(4)} ${convertTo}`;
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Crypto Currency Converter",
  "description": "A simple crypto currency converter.",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup/ccc.html"
  }
}
```

Right now the button to submit works if I click it, but when I hit 'Enter' the number input resets (clears), loses focus, and it doesn't seem to trigger the `convert` function.

I'm trying to make it so that when I click the button, or hit enter the convert function will be triggered.

Comment: I think the form is getting submitted, try `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` before if statement in the `keydown` callback

Comment: There's no server inside an extension so your `<form>` simply resets the page. Remove this tag, you don't need it.

Comment: Removing <form> worked. Thanks for this @wOxxOm

Answer (score 0):

There's no server inside an extension so your `<form>` simply resets the page. Remove this tag, you don't need it.